# Can I take a still photo with my built-in webcam?

Tags: macbook-pro, photos, webcam

I have a MacBook Pro at work, but am new to Macs and have never used the webcam outside of Skype. Is it possible to take a still photo with the webcam?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes, use the Photo Booth application.

Answer (score 5):

Check out /Applications/[Photo Booth.app](http://www.apple.com/macosx/what-is-macosx/photo-booth.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can with PhotoBooth. You can also use all kinds of crazy effects. I suggest trying this when you don't have any important appointments later. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Photobooth in Finder under Applications
2. Take picture or a couple of pictures.
3. Click Export and choose a directory to save your picture and name your picture if you do not want the default name.